# Consumer restart when I reset Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka topic with data, called "topic01"

I want to create a consumer that every time I start my Spring Boot 2 application, start reading that topic from the beginning.

I have the following code, that if I add something new to the topic if it reaches me, but when starting the first time, it won't read me from the beginning of the topic.

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic01")
public void listenTopic01(ConsumerRecord<String, MiDTO> consumerRecord) throws Exception {
    logger.info("KafkaHandler");
    logger.info(consumerRecord.value().toString());
    logger.info(consumerRecord.key().toString());
    latch.countDown();
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=XXXXX
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
```

What configuration should I add, so that this @KafkaListener reads the topic from the beginning, every time I restart my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use a unique (random) group-id each time, or have your listener class implement `ConsumerSeekAware` and add

```java
@Override
public void onPartitionsAssigned(Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
    consumer.seekToBeginning(partitions);
}
```

or

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic01", 
    groupId = "#{T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID().toString()}")
```